# sql query Issue: Getting at least 1 column by default

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am getting table data by parameter **@UserId_Fk** .
If **@UserId_Fk** is equal to 2 , it gets the result correct.
If it is 3 or any other , I get the result correct but with one top row of **UserId_Fk** 2.

Table Structure:

```
TestId  int 
UserId_Fk   int  
CheckInTime datetime 
LoginStatus char(1)
```

Sample Data:

```
  Id     UserId_Fk        CheckInTime        LoginStatus
   1    2   2013-01-01 12:00:00.000      I
   2    2   2013-12-22 13:01:01.000      O
   3    2   2013-12-22 13:49:54.000      I
   4    2   2013-12-22 13:49:55.000      I
   5    2   2013-12-22 15:58:42.000      O
   6    3   2013-12-23 06:02:58.000      I
   7    3   2013-12-23 14:00:29.000      O
   8    3   2013-12-24 05:17:09.000      I
   9    3   2013-12-24 12:34:25.000      O
   10   3   2013-12-24 12:34:26.000      O
```

Here is my stored procedure to get the Table

```
createproc [dbo].[GetCheckInCheckOutTable]
   @UserId_Fk  int

   as
   begin
   SELECT 
  t.UserId_Fk
, [Date] = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.CheckIn))
, CheckIn = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.CheckIn, 108)
, CheckOut = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.CheckOut, 108)
, [Hours] = CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.CheckIn, t.CheckOut) / 60. AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM (
SELECT 
      t.UserId_Fk
    , CheckIn = t.CheckInTime
    , CheckOut = r.CheckInTime
    , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.UserId_Fk, r.CheckInTime ORDER BY 1/0)
FROM UserTime t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM UserTime t2
    WHERE t2.UserId_Fk = t.@UserId_Fk
        AND t2.CheckInTime > t.CheckInTime
        AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.CheckInTime)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t2.CheckInTime))
        AND t2.LoginStatus = 'O'
    ORDER BY t2.CheckInTime
) r
WHERE t.LoginStatus = 'I'
) t
WHERE t.RowNum = 1
end
```

Comment: Do you need to match the row's UserId_Fk against the specified @UserId_Fk on the left side of the APPLY?

Comment: Yes.. I pass it as Session Id of that Users whose  Id is UserId_Fk. In simple , I want to get this table based on UserId_Fk passed.

Comment: Try adding to the existing WHERE : `WHERE t.LoginStatus = 'I' AND t.UserId_Fk=@UserId_Fk` ?